# When a Snapshot occurs, does this benefit all nodes automatically?

Tags: snapshot

So, when a snapshot is made, how will this affect my node?

Is the node intelligent enough to download the snapshot and purge the database, or does this occur through sync? Or does the node owner need to delete the database, download the new, almost empty one, and sync again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot is currently "distributed" in the form of a new iri release. When node operators update, they have to delete the database (or the node will not start). No need to manually download a new database as the number of transactions is low and the transactions will be fed by the (already updated) neighbors.

There are plans for more automatic snapshots, but since they are plans, it is not known how exactly they will work once finished.

Comment: I upgraded to IRI 1.4.1.4 today, but I didn't delete the database and it didn't complain.

Comment: @DanielF While every snapshot comes with a new iri release, not every iri release will contain a new snapshot. So far, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1 came with a new snapshot and the others did not.